# Java, Email and how to catch messages not being sent

Tags: java, email, exim

I have a Java app that sends email via a localhost Exim4 mail server. Email sending works great using the javax.mail.* classes however...

I'm trying to catch any failed messages - messages that bounce. I've read a million blog posts and Q&As on here saying it's not possible. It's obviously possible because sites such as my bank can detect when one of their emails is not delivered to my address due to downtime of my mail server.

I can see in the Exim log that the email has bounced - if I use asdf@asdf.com for example - and I want that info. I understand about how Exim (and most mail servers) accept the message and then add it to a queue to send long after the client has been disconnected. One option is of course to watch the log. I'm reluctant to do that though, as there must be a better way.

I'm not limited by technology choices, other than it needs to be GPL-esq, and Java needs to do the sending and processing of failures (as details are written to DBs).

I've tried Aspirin, but I found the documentation lacking and struggled to get the listeners working the way that I wanted.

Does anyone have any ideas? Can you point me in the right direction?

// Edit

I just wanted to clarify what I mean by success - I appreciate that some servers may accept the mail but it may never make it to a users inbox due to various reasons (spam for example) and I realise I can't detect that. What I want to detect is when an email is visibly rejected by a mail server.

I'm looking into setting up a catch all for bounced emails on my Exim server and polling that every N minutes to check for failures. It looks like I can hide an ID in a message header to make it more program friendly. Perhaps I need to look into Aspirin again...

// Answer

To answer this, with the option that I took...

I used Aspirin for Java in the end... it works well with one exception - I can't seem to remove the 60 second delay between queueing email to send, and it actually being sent.

I used this code in my 'start up Aspirin class'

```
MailComplete mc = new MailComplete();
AspirinInternal.addListener(mc);
```

And this class for doing the 'mail completed' work.

```
import org.masukomi.aspirin.core.listener.AspirinListener;
import org.masukomi.aspirin.core.listener.ResultState;

public class MailComplete implements AspirinListener{

    @Override
    public void delivered(String string, String string1, ResultState rs, String string2) {     
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Note that only when a completed mail is sent does this listener fire. The ResultState seems to be mostly NULL which is a bit useless. Basically, if this class fires, then it's most likely that the email has sent.

So far it seems to have worked in my basic tests, but it's not ideal and the code seems to be a bit flakey with the NULL business. As I say, it seems to work but with the lack of docs on the matter, it's difficult to say if this is the best it can be.

If anyone lands on this by chance, and has a better idea, or better code, I'd be very interested.

Cheers.

Comment: Your title is incorrect. JavaMail catches mails that aren't sent at all by throwing exceptions. What you're looking for is a solution that scans your inbox for bounce messages. Please clarify your title.

Comment: It catches mails that aren't added to the delivery process, but has no conception of mails being sent or not, at least as my understanding goes.